# Android Login Form UI

Tags: android, user-interface

Does anyone know how it is possible to create a Login Form on Android with curved edit texts?

For example like IOS:

[image: img]

Are there any good UI tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a 9-patch drawable and define it as the background for each textview.

but remember that copying UI elements from different platforms is not only is a general bad practice in any platform but as well is not recommended but the official Android design guidelines.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 2):

Just create a drawable resource that specifies the way the EditText will be drawn:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
 android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then, just reference this drawable in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<EditText  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not affiliated with them but it's a really great UI Framework: http://kivy.org

It works with Android [1] (and many others) and is OpenSource (you will find it on Github)

[1] http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html